# Laravel correct way to bind data in raw sql string

Tags: laravel-5

I am using `?` identifier for my `DB::insert()` and its working great, but I am having problem for my `DB::select()`, the `?` doesn't work.

Here's my query:

```
    $result = DB::select("
        SELECT `department_code`, `name` FROM `tbl_departments` 
        WHERE `department_code` LIKE '%?%' OR `name` LIKE '%?%'
    ", [
        $searchkey, $searchkey
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition1 =: 'column'";
$result = DB::select(DB::raw($query),['column'=>'value]);
```

in my case it's working.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use laravel query then you can use it like this way pretty easy to understand to everyone

```
DB::table('your_table_name')->where('field_name',$variable)
                            ->select('fieldname','fieldname')
                            ->first();
```

or you can use get() for retrieving all data. for further assistance you can check [here][1]

[1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries or if you want with select query then

```
$ousers = DB::SELECT("SELECT
                                user.id as ouser_id,
                                user.name as ouser_name,
                                user.username as ouser_username,
                                user.phone_no as ouser_phone_number,
                                user.email as ouser_email,
                                user.pic as ouser_pic
                                FROM user
                                WHERE user.id != :userid1 AND user.flag = 1
                                AND user.id NOT IN
                                            (SELECT blocked_id FROM blockeds WHERE blocker_id = :userid2
                                                UNION
                                            (SELECT blocker_id FROM blockeds WHERE blocked_id = :userid3)
                                                UNION
                                            (SELECT sender_id FROM friends WHERE receiver_id = :userid4)
                                                UNION
                                            (SELECT receiver_id FROM friends WHERE sender_id = :userid5)
                                            )
                                HAVING ( (ouser_username LIKE '".$data['search']."%') OR (ouser_name LIKE '".$data['search']."%'))
                        ",array('userid1'=>$user->id,'userid2'=>$user->id,'userid3'=>$user->id,'userid4'=>$user->id,'userid5'=>$user->id));
```

Comment: As a developer myself I wanted to keep my knowledge using a standard SQL syntax and never depend on any query builder.

Comment: check now this might be what you need

Answer (score -1):

apparently this works

```
$result = DB::select("
    SELECT `department_code`, `name` FROM `tbl_departments` 
    WHERE `department_code` LIKE '%$searchkey%' OR `name` LIKE '%$searchkey%'
");
```